# Proper way to close a crypto ssh session freeing all resources in golang?

Tags: go, ssh, pipe

**TL;DR** - What is the proper way to close a `golang.org/x/crypto/ssh` session freeing all resources?

My investigation thus far:

The `golang.org/x/crypto/ssh` `*Session` has a `Close()` function which calls the `*Channel` `Close()` function which sends a message (I'm guessing to the remote server) to close, but I don't see anything about closing other resources like the pipe returned from the `*Session` `StdoutPipe()` function.

Looking at the `*Session` `Wait()` code, I see that the `*Session stdinPipeWriter` is closed but nothing about the `stdoutPipe`.

This package feels a lot like the `os/exec` package which guarantees that using the `os/exec Wait()` function will clean up all the resources. Doing some light digging there shows some similarities in the `Wait()` functions. Both use the following construct to report errors on `io.Copy` calls to their stdout, stderr, stdin readers/writers (well if I'm reading this correctly actually only one error) - crypto package shown:

```
var copyError error
for _ = range s.copyFuncs {
    if err := <-s.errors; err != nil && copyError == nil {
        copyError = err
    }
}
```

But the `os/exec` `Wait()` also calls this close descriptor method

```
c.closeDescriptors(c.closeAfterWait)
```

which is just calling the close method on a slice of `io.Closer` interfaces:

```
func (c *Cmd) closeDescriptors(closers []io.Closer) {
    for _, fd := range closers {
        fd.Close()
    }
}
```

when `os/exec` creates the pipe, it tracks what needs closing:

```
func (c *Cmd) StdoutPipe() (io.ReadCloser, error) {
if c.Stdout != nil {
    return nil, errors.New("exec: Stdout already set")
}
if c.Process != nil {
    return nil, errors.New("exec: StdoutPipe after process started")
}
pr, pw, err := os.Pipe()
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
c.Stdout = pw
c.closeAfterStart = append(c.closeAfterStart, pw)
c.closeAfterWait = append(c.closeAfterWait, pr)
return pr, nil
}
```

During this I noticed that `x/cyrpto/ssh` `*Session StdoutPipe()` returns an `io.Reader` and `ox/exec` returns an `io.ReadCloser`. And `x/crypto/ssh` does not track what to close. I can't find a call to `os.Pipe()` in the library so maybe the implementation is different and I'm missing something and confused by the Pipe name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A session is closed by calling `Close()`. There are no file descriptors involved, nor are there any calls to `os.Pipe` as the "pipe" returned from `Session.StdOutPipe` is only a pipe in concept and is of type `ssh.Channel`. Go channels don't need to be closed, because closing a channel is not a cleanup operation, rather it's simply a type of message sent to the channel. There is only ever one network connection involved in the ssh transport.

The only resource you need to close is the network connection; there are no other system resources to be freed. Calling `Close()` on the `ssh.Client` will call `ssh.Conn.Close`, and in turn close the `net.Conn`.

If you need the handle the network connection, you can always skip the `ssh.Dial` convenience function and Dial the network connection yourself:

```
c, err := net.DialTimeout(network, addr, timeout)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
conn, chans, reqs, err := ssh.NewClientConn(c, addr, config)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

// calling conn.Close will close the underlying net.Conn

client := ssh.NewClient(c, chans, reqs)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. So be to clear a call to `Session.Wait()` should then be followed by a call to `Session.Close()` for non-leaky use?

Comment: Also, my understanding is that while channels don't need to be closed per se, calling close on a channel can be used to signal upstream or downstream goroutines that no more information should be sent/received. This is because that goroutine can hang/leak if it is trying to send/receive on a unbuffered channel that will never be pulled from/sent to, correct?

Comment: @darkwing: calling `Session.Close()` is more about properly using the ssh protocol, where you inform the server that you wish to close the channel. It's actually the receipt of the server's close message that removes the ssh "channel" data structure from multiplexer. Yes, closing a go channel can trigger cleanup or unblock goroutines, but only if the code is structured that way. There's no reason to assume not closing a channel is going to leak resources any more than any other action you could take.

Comment: Good clarification. The answer to my first comment is no, `Session.Wait()` receives the server's close message and (just tested this) calling `Session.Close()` after `Session.Wait()` gives an EOF error. `Session.Close()` needs only to be used when something weird happens in the middle of the session and we want to exit - like an error calling `Session.StdoutPipe()` or `Session.RequestPty()`